# Showing the previously selected value in a multi-select option

Tags: php, html, database, multi-select

Thanks for reading.

I am using the following multiselect option for a users 'interests'. They can pick one or many. The interests are then stored in the database as a string, which is created from the array that the code below supplies. The thing is, when the user returns to modify his/her interests I want the box to display whats already in the database. The value for this is $user->interests (which is a string). I can't see how I can perform this. You can see I added $user->interest below to the value of the . Obviously this doesn't work. Any ideas...?

```
<select name="interests[]" value="<?php echo $user->interests;?>" style="width:390px;" data-placeholder="Select your specialist interests"  class="chosen-select" multiple tabindex="6">
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option value="Acute critical care">Acute critical care</option>
                            <option value="Allergic diseases">Allergic diseases</option>
                            <option value="Asthma">Asthma</option>
                            <option value="Bronchiectasis">Bronchiectasis</option>
                            <option value="Cardiology">Cardiology</option>

</select>
```

Comment: what does var_dump($user->interest ) shows ?

Comment: "The interests are then stored in the database as a string" — Don't do that, use a [junction table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table).

Comment: Quentin, Why do you say that. My site creates the string....no issue of injection....unless I am mistaken. Please elaborate.

Comment: Read [the link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) ([this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table)) that Quentin posted in his comment. A junction table has nothing to do with SQL injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The select element doesn't have a value attribute.

You need to add a `selected` attribute to *each* of the `<option>`s that should be selected by default.

You should get the list of values in an array and then check to see if each option is [in that array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) as you output them.

Comment: Quentin, apologies. Could you elaborate on 'You need to add a selected attribute to each of the <option>s that should be selected by default.' please.....many thanks

Comment: `<option ... selected>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this variant.

```
<select name="interests[]" style="width:390px;" data-placeholder="Select your specialist interests"  class="chosen-select" multiple tabindex="6">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="Acute critical care"
 <?php if(strpos( $user->interests,"Acute critical care")){echo 'selected="selected"'} ?> >
Acute critical care
</option>
//Similarly for other options.
//....

</select>
```

Comment: Do you see any specific errors? The answer was just a hint. It can be easily fixed though.

Comment: Are you using any UI (like jQueryUI) for multi select?